Failed to read a output variable returned by a terraform module when upgraded terraform-provider-google from version v4.85.0 to 5.x.x
I have a module that return a variable named "spot_account_id" and we use this variable to create other terraform resource further.
Terraform plan is working fine untill I'm not upgrading google provider version.
As soon I upgrade google provider version from v4.85.0 to v5.39.0 and perform terraform plan, I'm unable to get "spot_account_id" from module in return.
Note:
In module we have data external resource https://github.com/spotinst/terraform-spotinst-gcp-connect/blob/main/data.tf which is responsible to execute python code which take "name" as input and return "spot_account_id" https://github.com/spotinst/terraform-spotinst-gcp-connect/blob/main/scripts/spot_account.py.
Terraform-provider-google: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest
My local setup details mentioned below:
Terraform version: 1.3.8
python version: 3.11.3
I'm expecting the same behavior and "spot_account_id" in return from terraform module even after upgrading terraform-provider-google as I have when I'm using v4.x.x.
